# :root vs html - which is faster?

Tags: css

I have a CSS stylesheet that contains a lot of declarations starting with `html.some-class`. Now I'm wondering if there would be any difference if I wrote `:root.some-class`.

I suppose that the browser may scan the whole DOM to try to apply the `html.some-class` rule, because there might be an invalid document with more than one `<html>` tag. On the other hand, in a valid HTML document (and I can be sure that the styled document is standard-compliant) there is only one root element, so that the `:root` search doesn't have to traverse the whole tree.

Taking the above into consideration, would my stylesheet be more efficiently applied if I used `:root` instead of `html`?

Footnote: I'm not able to get rid of the selector targeting the `<html>` tag.

Comment: I seriously doubt there's any perceivable difference between these two, other than `:root` having a higher specify, they should be identical when used in an HTML document.

Comment: I was given to understand that the `html` selector (at one time, at least) was regarded inconsistently by different browsers so `:root` was introduced as a universal standard. That may _not_ be correct (I can't find a source) but **MDN** states: _"`:root` represents the `<html>` element and is identical to the selector `html`, except that its specificity is higher."_ (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)